# How to parse node js response of mongodb data in angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mongodb

I've an http server in node [not express]. On button click I've a get method, which then pulls documents from mongodb (using mongoose) and displays it on angular page.

on button click:

```
       $http.get('/get').success(function(response){
         console.log(response);
       //logic to store JSON response of database and perform repeat to display each document returned on UI
       });
```

In Node code where server is created using http.createServer instead of express:

```
     if(req.url==="/get"){
      res.writeHead(200,{'content-type':'text/plain'});
      modelName.find({}, 'property1 prop2 prop3', function(err,docs){
        res.write('response...:  '+docs);
       });
     }
```

Here is my issue:
I'm able to send response from node js to angular js but how to parse it? If I don't add 'response...:' before docs then I get an error msg 'first argument should be a string or buffer'. On angular I get response like:->

```
      response...:{_id:....1, prop1: 'a',prop2: 'b',prop3: 'c'},
      {_id:....2, prop1: 'ab',prop2: 'bc',prop3: 'cd'}
```

I want to display documents as a tabular format

Comment: Send `json` instead of `plain string` like: `res.write({'response':docs});`

Comment: Still getting same error 'first argument should be a string or buffer'

Comment: You can actually set Content-Type:'application/json' .  If you are getting the same error after this also do res.send(JSON.stringify(docs));

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your exact setup, but I think you should transfer `application/json` instead of `text/plain`.

You cannot simply concatenate a string to `docs`, you need to return either only just `docs` (to transfer as an array) or write `res.write({'response':docs})` (to transfer as an object).

Consider moving from $http to a resource service. In your resource service, you need to set `isArray` to false if you want to transfer as an object or to true if you transfer as an array: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource

Comment: still getting same error 'first argument should be a string or buffer'.

Comment: Do look into the request in Firefox/Chrome dev tool to see what type the response is, I suspect it is still plain text.

Comment: Are you getting this error from Node or in the browser. Either way, can you post the stack trace?